# Хранение подписок в одной ячейке

Tags: php, mysql

Если хранить подписки в одной ячейке, то в каком виде, и как туда добавлять новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

либо json, либо serialize, либо csv. Чего уж там...

Но хранить в одной ячейке - ПЛОХО. 
Как минимум, потому что для добавления вам придется ее скачать, распарсить и переписать.
Почитайте про третью нормальную форму.

Comment: поиграем в nosql : )

Comment: поиграем в idontkNOwSQL?

Comment: так блин тут пишут, что лучше в одной ячейке хранить 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/201072/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4
http://hashcode.ru/questions/197883/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: В первом случае речи об одном поле нет. У вас может быть таблица вида:

123 / 7493
123 / 57759
123 / 23441
123 / 46532

Во втором случае таки предлагают, но даже сказано КАК хранить.

Comment: @knes я так понял, что тогда лайки, репосты и заметки тоже надо хранить не в одном поле?

Comment: Ага, тогда вы сможете легко их обновлять одним запросом: 

     update `post_info` set `like`=`like`+1

Answer (score 0):

Может, просто числа текстом через запятую?

```
8493,67759,33441,565327
```